# NSPredicate - Contains Not Functioning As Expected

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am using NSPredicate on a NSMutableArray as follows, filled from an XML Sheet

```
//Get XML Data
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"breosla_db" ofType:@"xml"];
NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLFile:filePath];
//Place in Mutable Array
NSMutableArray *data = [xmlDoc valueForKeyPath:@"row"];
NSLog(@"Data %@", data[0]);

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID contains[c] '2'"];
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
```

The data looks like this in the log:

```
Data {
ID =     (
    2
);
address1 =     (
    "123 Fake Street"
);
address2 =     (
    "A Sleepy Town"
);
address3 =     (
);
county =     (
);
licenseNo =     (
    12345
);
licenseType =     (
    "Trader"
);
licenseeName =     (
    "Mr. Trader"
);
nominessName =     (
);
tradingName =     (
    "Trading Shop"
);
```

}

The current predicate:

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID contains[c] '2'"];
```

Only returns the data where ID == 2, it does not return 12, 22, 42 etc for example.

Secondly, I cannot filter by the e.g. All names that contain 'e':

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tradingName contains[c] 'e'"];
```

The 'data' NSMutableArray, in each position, contains data similar to that show in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data comprises an array of dictionaries, and the values for each of the dictionary keys are also (single element) arrays.  You can see this because your log shows

```
ID =     (
    2
);
etc
```

The ( ) denote arrays.  So, to get your predicates to work, you need to use 'ANY', as follows:

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY ID contains[c] '2'"];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tradingName contains[c] 'e'"];
```

But you might do better to remodel your data so that the values are not embedded in arrays.

Comment: This is correct and yes, my data needs to be remodeled! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your predicate will work for only ID or tradingName. Assuming data[0] holds complete xml element, instead use following;

```
NSPredicate *idPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] '2'"];
[data filterUsingPredicate:idPredicate];
```

And for tradingName that contains 'e':

```
NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'e'"];
[data filterUsingPredicate:namePredicate];
```

Check this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) for more help.